# Spring Activiti Gateway

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I'm a complete noob at both Spring AND Activiti, so this should be one heck of a question. I apologise in advance if my question is poorly constructed or something.

Here's a part of my activiti diagram:

[image]

First things first:

On Service Task "Create Laptop Request", the app saves to the database. This works fine.

On User Task "Approve Request", the `processInstanceId` is also saved into the database.

And then, the gateway comes in.

So, first off:

1. Did I use the right gateway? Such that if the response is yes, BOTH yes paths will be taken?
2. For the sake of simplicity, let's say both `yes` and `no` paths lead to an End Task. Where do I put the listener / class, and what do I put in it? Is there a sample template of sorts? Maybe just a basic "true" or "false" could do for now.
3. Lastly, I've seen online that for two paths to converge to a single task, it has to go through a gateway - though not always. When is it appropriate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the user guide:

> The functionality of the inclusive gateway is based on the incoming
>   and outgoing sequence flow:
>
> fork: all outgoing sequence flow conditions are evaluated and for the
>   sequence flow conditions that evaluate to true the flows are followed
>   in parallel, creating one concurrent execution for each sequence flow.
>   join: all concurrent executions arriving at the inclusive gateway wait
>   in the gateway until an execution has arrived for each of the incoming
>   sequence flows that have a process token. This is an important
>   difference with the parallel gateway. So in other words, the inclusive
>   gateway will only wait for the incoming sequence flows that will be
>   executed. After the join, the process continues past the joining
>   inclusive gateway.

So to answer your questions you need to look into xml representation of the scheme.

Defining an inclusive gateway needs one line of XML:

```
<inclusiveGateway id="myInclusiveGateway" />
```

But the actual behavior (fork, join or both), is defined by the sequence flows connected to the inclusive gateway.

If you want to, you may read the [manual](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html) 8.4.3. Inclusive Gateway. It is very usefull.